# After viewing a question from search, I'm losing the "pagination"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

To reproduce:

- select a tag
- scroll down to load at least one more page
- select a question from that new "page"
- come back to search results

You have lost your page, you need to scroll down again to see the previous selected question

Here is a video/gif to illustrate (not a perfect quality :-/)

[image]

I'm using the 0.1.16 version.

Comment: Looking into it.

Comment: (@BenCollins: you've removed your answer but here is my comment) I've just try again and the behavior is different now. When I came back to the list (ie.: a search for a custom tag) the search result was empty and got refilled. Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: that is the buggy behavior that happens to do something that doesn't seem all that buggy.  I deleted my answer because I got a repro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For searches that came from navigation (i.e., you tapped a tag and the query was auto-filled for you), we start the search as soon as the view becomes visible.  Because  `-[UIViewController:viewDidAppear:]` gets fired both when you come to the view and when you come *back* to it (as you would expect), the search is started when you navigate back, which has the effect of refreshing your results list.  We just weren't checking to see if you were coming back from somewhere or if this was the first view after navigating.

This is fixed and will be in the next build (tomorrow, likely).